# How to respectively give an upper bound for $\|XX^T\|_2$ and $diag (UXX^TU^T)$ with each column vector $\|x_i\|_2\leq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $X\in R^{d\times n}$, with each column vector $\|x_i\|_2\leq 1, 1\leq i\leq n$. Then how to respectively give an upper bound for $\|XX^T\|_2$ and $diag (UXX^TU^T)$? where $\|Y\|_2$ is l2-norm for vector or spectral norm for matrix $Y$, $UU^T=U^TU=I$, and $diag(Y)$ means a square diagonal matrix that only keeps the diagonal part of $Y$.

My bounds are both $n$, and could someone give tighter bounds for them respectively? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the bound for $\|XX^T\|_2$ is already tight, as seen with
$$
X = \pmatrix{1&\cdots&1\\0&\cdots&0\\ 
\vdots&\ddots & \vdots \\
0&\cdots & 0}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think that this means that the bound is *sharp*, not necessarily tight (which in a sense represents how close the bound is to the actual value).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel ah, whoops, and thank you for the clarification. I always get those terms mixed